# ZSTD equivalent of ZLIB deflateInit2 method

Tags: c++, initialization, zlib, zstd

In a c++ project I have a function using deflateInit2 method of ZLIB.

```
ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT deflateInit2 OF((z_streamp strm,
                                     int  level,
                                     int  method,
                                     int  windowBits,
                                     int  memLevel,
                                     int  strategy));
```

Now I am trying to find a similar functionality for ZSTD. For example the `windowBits` part is resolved by calling the

```
ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter(this->context, ZSTD_c_windowLog, windowBits);
```

methon of ZSTD. The `strategy` also has such an equivalent. The main question concerns memLevel. How to specify something like memLevel ZLIB parameter for ZSTD?

Answer (score 1):

Use the parameter `ZSTD_c_jobSize` as in

```cpp
ZSTD_CCtx_setParameter(this->context,ZSTD_c_jobSize,maxSize);
```

Job size must be a minimum of overlap size, or ZSTDMT_JOBSIZE_MIN (= 512 KB), whichever is largest.

https://zstd.docsforge.com/dev/api/ZSTD_cParameter/#ZSTD_c_jobSize